# How to put JSON array inside HTTP PUT call using REST Assured?

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Am using rest assured to test an API which requires me to conduct an HTTP PUT with a JSON array, for the request body, which only looks like this:

```
["6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
```

Please note that this doesn't require the opening and closing { } - just the square brackets.

---

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

---

MyApiRestTest.java:

```
public class MyApiRestTest {
 
      private static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/ams/rest";
      private static final String TOKEN = "AMIIinPiyPqMpViABA41HL8xTSsf";

      private static RequestSpecification requestSpec;

      @BeforeAll
      public static void setUpHeaders() {
          RequestSpecBuilder builder = new RequestSpecBuilder();
          builder.addHeader("Token", TOKEN);
          builder.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
          builder.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
          requestSpec = builder.build();
          requestSpec.config(RestAssured.config().objectMapperConfig(new ObjectMapperConfig(ObjectMapperType.GSON)));
      }


      @Test
      @DisplayName("PUT /v1/uids/{public-id}")
      public void updateUids() {
          String publicId = "ABCD786EFGH45";

          List<String> uids = new ArrayList<>();

          uids.add("6");
          uids.add("7");
          uids.add("8");
          uids.add("9");
          uids.add("10");

          given().spec(requestSpec)
               .pathParam("public-id", publicId)
               .body(uids)
          .when()
               .put(BASE_URL + "/v1/uids/{public-id}")
               .then()
               .statusCode(200);
      }

}
```

---

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> but was <404>.
```

Tried using different variations / approaches of this JSON array by doing this:

First approach:

```
String jsonArray = "[\"6\", \"7\", \"8\", \"9\", \"10\"]";
```

and subsequently:

```
given().spec(requestSpec)
       .pathParam("public-id", publicId)
       .body(jsonArray)
.when()
       .put(BASE_URL + "/v1/uids/{public-id}")
       .then()
       .statusCode(200);
```

---

Second approach:

Using `String[] uidsArray = {"6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};`

and subsequently:

```
given().spec(requestSpec)
       .pathParam("public-id", publicId)
       .body(uidsArray)
.when()
       .put(BASE_URL + "/v1/uids/{public-id}")
       .then()
       .statusCode(200);
```

Both variations give me the same exact error as the one that provided in the full source listing (see above):

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> but was <404>.
```

---

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 404 error means your resource was not found, which would indicate that the URL is incorrect rather than any issue with the request body content.

Comment: One - you are correct, I had some typos in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

It may be about the URL, I can see it is `BASE_URL + "/v1/uids/{public-id}"`. I think you want `{public-id}` to become an `id` when it executes, but it does not. Replace that part with the string form of the actual `id` may solve your issue.

Comment: The ```{public-id}``` is a required path param which can not be hardcoded. This same call works in my GET calls.